# MVC JQuery member not found

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer

The message in title I get when I fire an application in debug mode and only in IE.
Application stops, this message is shown and file points to  "jquery-1.8.2.min.js". Scaffolding engine added this three references.

```
 <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js") %>"></script>
 <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>"></script>
 <script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") %>"></script>
```

When I comment this,everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

That Url mapping appears unneeded in MVC. Just try this (and make sure the filenames are correct pf course):

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

I am thinking the error is actually a result of "other" code, so you may need to post more details once you change these script includes.

**Suggestion:** *If you are going to use MVC then use the bundling mechanism and take advantage of caching and automatic version matching & minification.* :)

Comment: For some unknown reasons everything now work just fine. I tried to paste this three lines of code (with URL mapping) on other view and app didn't break. I will give you one point for your effort but won't mark as preferred solution until I publish it.